# Script Launched via Start-Process works 90% of the time - when it "fails", it simply becomes a zombie and doesn't execute 1st line of code

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, unc, start-process

(Solved)

Task Scheduler launches a powershell job (no one is logged in, the task has a saved user) that then launches a CMD file from Powershell via Start-Process and that command file successfully launches powershell on another script with the correct parameter.  However, that ps1 script only seems to run 90% of the time.  The other 10% it doesn't even execute the 1st line.  I'm stumped, so here are the basics and what I can see in the windows logs...

```
$DailyDir      = "\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily"
$BatchDir      = "$DailyDir\BatchFiles"
$MobileMonCMD  = "$BatchDir\MobileMonitor.cmd"
$currentHour   = Get-Date -Format "HH"
$BackGroundPID = (Start-Process -FilePath $MobileMonCMD -ArgumentList $currentHour -WindowStyle Hidden -WorkingDirectory $BatchDir -PassThru).Id
```

I have verified that the cmd runs even on a "fail".  It appears in windows event viewer and I can see it create a call to the powershell script that I want running in the background.  The CMD file contents are:

```
@ECHO OFF
powershell "& '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' %1"
```

The very first line of code in MobileMonitor.ps1 is:

```
Start-Transcript -OutputDirectory "C:\Projects\Logs\MobileMonitor"
```

When my script is successful, I get a full transcript.  When it is not, nothing is generated.

The weird part is the powershell process for that run is still running (I am able to determine its assigned PID by following the trail through the windows events).

Below, I've included the Audit events showing the 11am one launching .. all appears well, except this one never executed "Start-Transcript".  Again, this works fine 90% of the time.  I get a nice transcript file.  But the other 10% has me stumped.

Is it an issue getting \\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\etc files?  Like it can't pull the file so it decides to sit as a zombie powershell process doing nothing?

Any advice appreciated.  On a side note, I have dozens of scripts running from that location.  This is the only one who complains (also the only one launching from Start-Process).

Here are the window audit events showing the 11am one getting all the way to Engine Available:

```
Log Name:      Windows PowerShell
Source:        PowerShell
Date:          8/11/2020 11:34:15 AM
Event ID:      400
Task Category: Engine Lifecycle
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Machine.Domain.com
Description:
Engine state is changed from None to Available. 

Details: 
    NewEngineState=Available
    PreviousEngineState=None

    SequenceNumber=13

    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    HostId=2d2852c6-19d0-46c4-bca8-d8528b46eb96
    HostApplication=powershell & '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' 11
    EngineVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    RunspaceId=1eee2a6e-95f9-40be-ac2d-707c2d0afe44
    PipelineId=
    CommandName=
    CommandType=
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="PowerShell" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">400</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>4</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-08-11T15:34:15.442775300Z" />
    <EventRecordID>62810</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Windows PowerShell</Channel>
    <Computer>Machine.Domain.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Available</Data>
    <Data>None</Data>
    <Data>  NewEngineState=Available
    PreviousEngineState=None

    SequenceNumber=13

    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    HostId=2d2852c6-19d0-46c4-bca8-d8528b46eb96
    HostApplication=powershell &amp; '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' 11
    EngineVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    RunspaceId=1eee2a6e-95f9-40be-ac2d-707c2d0afe44
    PipelineId=
    CommandName=
    CommandType=
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Windows PowerShell
Source:        PowerShell
Date:          8/11/2020 11:34:15 AM
Event ID:      600
Task Category: Provider Lifecycle
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Machine.Domain.com
Description:
Provider "Variable" is Started. 

Details: 
    ProviderName=Variable
    NewProviderState=Started

    SequenceNumber=11

    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    HostId=2d2852c6-19d0-46c4-bca8-d8528b46eb96
    HostApplication=powershell & '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' 11
    EngineVersion=
    RunspaceId=
    PipelineId=
    CommandName=
    CommandType=
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="PowerShell" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">600</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>6</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-08-11T15:34:15.442775300Z" />
    <EventRecordID>62809</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Windows PowerShell</Channel>
    <Computer>Machine.Domain.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Variable</Data>
    <Data>Started</Data>
    <Data>  ProviderName=Variable
    NewProviderState=Started

    SequenceNumber=11

    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    HostId=2d2852c6-19d0-46c4-bca8-d8528b46eb96
    HostApplication=powershell &amp; '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' 11
    EngineVersion=
    RunspaceId=
    PipelineId=
    CommandName=
    CommandType=
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Windows PowerShell
Source:        PowerShell
Date:          8/11/2020 11:34:15 AM
Event ID:      600
Task Category: Provider Lifecycle
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Machine.Domain.com
Description:
Provider "Function" is Started. 

Details: 
    ProviderName=Function
    NewProviderState=Started

    SequenceNumber=9

    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    HostId=2d2852c6-19d0-46c4-bca8-d8528b46eb96
    HostApplication=powershell & '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' 11
    EngineVersion=
    RunspaceId=
    PipelineId=
    CommandName=
    CommandType=
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="PowerShell" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">600</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>6</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-08-11T15:34:15.427147700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>62808</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Windows PowerShell</Channel>
    <Computer>Machine.Domain.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Function</Data>
    <Data>Started</Data>
    <Data>  ProviderName=Function
    NewProviderState=Started

    SequenceNumber=9

    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    HostId=2d2852c6-19d0-46c4-bca8-d8528b46eb96
    HostApplication=powershell &amp; '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' 11
    EngineVersion=
    RunspaceId=
    PipelineId=
    CommandName=
    CommandType=
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Windows PowerShell
Source:        PowerShell
Date:          8/11/2020 11:34:15 AM
Event ID:      600
Task Category: Provider Lifecycle
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Machine.Domain.com
Description:
Provider "FileSystem" is Started. 

Details: 
    ProviderName=FileSystem
    NewProviderState=Started

    SequenceNumber=7

    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    HostId=2d2852c6-19d0-46c4-bca8-d8528b46eb96
    HostApplication=powershell & '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' 11
    EngineVersion=
    RunspaceId=
    PipelineId=
    CommandName=
    CommandType=
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="PowerShell" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">600</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>6</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-08-11T15:34:15.427147700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>62807</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Windows PowerShell</Channel>
    <Computer>Machine.Domain.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>FileSystem</Data>
    <Data>Started</Data>
    <Data>  ProviderName=FileSystem
    NewProviderState=Started

    SequenceNumber=7

    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    HostId=2d2852c6-19d0-46c4-bca8-d8528b46eb96
    HostApplication=powershell &amp; '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' 11
    EngineVersion=
    RunspaceId=
    PipelineId=
    CommandName=
    CommandType=
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Windows PowerShell
Source:        PowerShell
Date:          8/11/2020 11:34:15 AM
Event ID:      600
Task Category: Provider Lifecycle
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Machine.Domain.com
Description:
Provider "Environment" is Started. 

Details: 
    ProviderName=Environment
    NewProviderState=Started

    SequenceNumber=5

    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    HostId=2d2852c6-19d0-46c4-bca8-d8528b46eb96
    HostApplication=powershell & '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' 11
    EngineVersion=
    RunspaceId=
    PipelineId=
    CommandName=
    CommandType=
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="PowerShell" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">600</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>6</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-08-11T15:34:15.427147700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>62806</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Windows PowerShell</Channel>
    <Computer>Machine.Domain.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Environment</Data>
    <Data>Started</Data>
    <Data>  ProviderName=Environment
    NewProviderState=Started

    SequenceNumber=5

    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    HostId=2d2852c6-19d0-46c4-bca8-d8528b46eb96
    HostApplication=powershell &amp; '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' 11
    EngineVersion=
    RunspaceId=
    PipelineId=
    CommandName=
    CommandType=
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Windows PowerShell
Source:        PowerShell
Date:          8/11/2020 11:34:15 AM
Event ID:      600
Task Category: Provider Lifecycle
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Machine.Domain.com
Description:
Provider "Alias" is Started. 

Details: 
    ProviderName=Alias
    NewProviderState=Started

    SequenceNumber=3

    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    HostId=2d2852c6-19d0-46c4-bca8-d8528b46eb96
    HostApplication=powershell & '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' 11
    EngineVersion=
    RunspaceId=
    PipelineId=
    CommandName=
    CommandType=
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="PowerShell" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">600</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>6</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-08-11T15:34:15.427147700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>62805</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Windows PowerShell</Channel>
    <Computer>Machine.Domain.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Alias</Data>
    <Data>Started</Data>
    <Data>  ProviderName=Alias
    NewProviderState=Started

    SequenceNumber=3

    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    HostId=2d2852c6-19d0-46c4-bca8-d8528b46eb96
    HostApplication=powershell &amp; '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' 11
    EngineVersion=
    RunspaceId=
    PipelineId=
    CommandName=
    CommandType=
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Windows PowerShell
Source:        PowerShell
Date:          8/11/2020 11:34:15 AM
Event ID:      600
Task Category: Provider Lifecycle
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Machine.Domain.com
Description:
Provider "Registry" is Started. 

Details: 
    ProviderName=Registry
    NewProviderState=Started

    SequenceNumber=1

    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    HostId=2d2852c6-19d0-46c4-bca8-d8528b46eb96
    HostApplication=powershell & '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' 11
    EngineVersion=
    RunspaceId=
    PipelineId=
    CommandName=
    CommandType=
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="PowerShell" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">600</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>6</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-08-11T15:34:15.427147700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>62804</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Windows PowerShell</Channel>
    <Computer>Machine.Domain.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Registry</Data>
    <Data>Started</Data>
    <Data>  ProviderName=Registry
    NewProviderState=Started

    SequenceNumber=1

    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3471
    HostId=2d2852c6-19d0-46c4-bca8-d8528b46eb96
    HostApplication=powershell &amp; '\\MACHINE-NAME\PathToStuff\Daily\BatchFiles\MobileMonitor.ps1' 11
    EngineVersion=
    RunspaceId=
    PipelineId=
    CommandName=
    CommandType=
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          8/11/2020 11:34:15 AM
Event ID:      4688
Task Category: Process Creation
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      Machine.Domain.com
Description:
A new process has been created.

Creator Subject:
    Security ID:        DOMAIN\Admin-User
    Account Name:       Admin-User
    Account Domain:     DOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0x1B20BED0

Target Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Acco## Heading ##unt Name:      -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Process Information:
    New Process ID:     0x1e90
    New Process Name:   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
    Token Elevation Type:   %%1936
    Mandatory Label:        Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level
    Creator Process ID: 0x1c28
    Creator Process Name:   C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
    Process Command Line:   

Token Elevation Type indicates the type of token that was assigned to the new process in accordance with User Account Control policy.

Type 1 is a full token with no privileges removed or groups disabled.  A full token is only used if User Account Control is disabled or if the user is the built-in Administrator account or a service account.

Type 2 is an elevated token with no privileges removed or groups disabled.  An elevated token is used when User Account Control is enabled and the user chooses to start the program using Run as administrator.  An elevated token is also used when an application is configured to always require administrative privilege or to always require maximum privilege, and the user is a member of the Administrators group.

Type 3 is a limited token with administrative privileges removed and administrative groups disabled.  The limited token is used when User Account Control is enabled, the application does not require administrative privilege, and the user does not choose to start the program using Run as administrator.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" />
    <EventID>4688</EventID>
    <Version>2</Version>
    <Level>0</Level>
    <Task>13312</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-08-11T15:34:15.011474000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>20585449</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="4796" />
    <Channel>Security</Channel>
    <Computer>Machine.Domain.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-21-1067277609-22629781-1543857936-67791</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserName">Admin-User</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">DOMAIN</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x1b20bed0</Data>
    <Data Name="NewProcessId">0x1e90</Data>
    <Data Name="NewProcessName">C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</Data>
    <Data Name="TokenElevationType">%%1936</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessId">0x1c28</Data>
    <Data Name="CommandLine">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="TargetUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetUserName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetDomainName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetLogonId">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="ParentProcessName">C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</Data>
    <Data Name="MandatoryLabel">S-1-16-12288</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 0):

A windows geek friend suggested I may have a race condition since this is running on a server with no one logged in so the call to the new background powershell process has to establish its environment.  He thought it might not have access to the \\MACHINE-NAME\PathToFiles\ps1Script area in time for the call on occasion.

To test this, I moved the code to the C drive on the server and it now works 100% of the time.  All of my other jobs that live on the \\NO-MACHINE location run fine from task scheduler, but this is the only one launched from Start-Process.  If someone can explain to me what about Start-Process is having problems or a way to allow it to have a full network enabled environment from which to call the script, I'd love to put the code back.

For now, I'm happy the problem is solved, but keeping code on the server instead of my centralized repository is going to annoy me to no end.  ;)